# iOS: sandbox of an iphone app

Tags: mobile, ios, sandbox

I am new to iOS so I do have only limited knowledge about iOS in general. For self learning purposes, I would like to know several things as I am quite confused after searching the web.

I do know that that there is a sandbox for each iphone app. So what I would like to understand is comparing a jailbroken and non jailbroken phone, would the sandbox still be available in each app at install? If so, is there any difference of the sandbox between a jailbroken phone and non jailbroken phone?

Also I would also wish to know the common types of data that are being probed from the sandbox. I believe it is not as simple as how I described.

Comment: This question is being [closed](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as too broad. I edited it down to focus on the part about security aspects of a sandbox. The part about which tools to use is off-topic here anyway (you can ask development questions on [so]).

Answer (score 2):

The sandbox restricts each application so that it can only read its own files, and must get explicit user permission for access to features like location, camera, microphone, etc. Cookies are stored per-app, and sqlite databases are files subject to the sandbox restrictions.

On any phone, jailbroken or not, some of the Apple apps are system apps which are not restricted by the sandbox.

On a jailbroken phone the sandbox is still enforced for standard apps. However, it becomes possible to create third-party system apps that are not restricted by the sandbox. The details vary depending on which jailbreak you use. There's good information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026920/why-sandbox-in-ios-6-1-1-still-exists-for-app-even-after-i-have-jailbreak